# I can read data from hive tables through hive client. But i cannot read from tools like talend

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have installed cdh4.4. And hive client is working properly and i am able to create, and display all the hive tables.
But when i use tools like talend i am getting the error 10001 table not found.

Can anybody tell where i am going wrong?

Comment: 1 more point i'd like to mention. tables can be read through hue. And from talend also i am able to read tables from database "default" but only databases created by users are not accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem is due to the reason that the tool talend searches the default database.
Hence give database.tablename in the table field. This will solve the problem.

Regards,
Nagaraj